# Define manually sorted MNIST dataset with batch size = 1 in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, mnist, batchsize, pytorch-dataloader

[] : this indicates a batch. For example, if the batch size is 5, then the batch will look something like this [1,4,7,4,2]. The length of [] indicates the batch size.

What I want to make a training set something looks like this:

[1] -> [1] -> [1] -> [1] -> [1] -> [7] -> [7] -> [7] -> [7] -> [7] -> [3] -> [3] -> [3] -> [3] -> [3] -> ... and so on

Which means that firstly five 1s (batch size = 1), secondly five 7s (batch size = 1), thirdly five 3s (batch size = 1) and so on...

Can someone please provide me an idea?

It will be very helpful if someone can explain how to implement this with codes.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a DataLoader where you just want to define the class label for each sample then you can make use of the [`torch.data.utils.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=subset#torch.utils.data.Subset) class. Despite its name it doesn't necessarily need to define a subset of dataset. For example

```py
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as T
from itertools import cycle

mnist = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./', train=True, transform=T.ToTensor())

# not sure what "...and so on" implies, but define this list however you like
target_classes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

# create cyclic iterators of indices for each class in MNIST
indices = dict()
for label in torch.unique(mnist.targets).tolist():
    indices[label] = cycle(torch.nonzero(mnist.targets == label).flatten().tolist())

# define the order of indices in the new mnist subset based on target_classes
new_indices = []
for t in target_classes:
    new_indices.append(next(indices[t]))

# create a Subset of MNIST based on new_indices
mnist_modified = torch.utils.data.Subset(mnist, new_indices)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_modified, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
    # training loop
    print(f'Batch {idx+1} labels: {y.tolist()}')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `DataLoader` that returns five samples in a row of the same class, but you don't want to define the class for each index manually then you can create a custom sampler. For example

```py
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as T
from itertools import cycle

class RepeatClassSampler(torch.utils.data.Sampler):
    def __init__(self, targets, repeat_count, length, shuffle=False):
        if not torch.is_tensor(targets):
            targets = torch.tensor(targets)

        self.targets = targets
        self.repeat_count = repeat_count
        self.length = length
        self.shuffle = shuffle

        self.classes = torch.unique(targets).tolist()
        self.class_indices = dict()
        for label in self.classes:
            self.class_indices[label] = torch.nonzero(targets == label).flatten() 

    def __iter__(self):
        class_index_iters = dict()
        for label in self.classes:
            if self.shuffle:
                class_index_iters[label] = cycle(self.class_indices[label][torch.randperm(len(self.class_indices))].tolist())
            else:
                class_index_iters[label] = cycle(self.class_indices[label].tolist())

        if self.shuffle:
            target_iter = cycle(self.targets[torch.randperm(len(self.targets))].tolist())
        else:
            target_iter = cycle(self.targets.tolist())

        def index_generator():
            for i in range(self.length):
                if i % self.repeat_count == 0:
                    current_class = next(target_iter)
                yield next(class_index_iters[current_class])
    
        return index_generator()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length


mnist = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./', train=True, transform=T.ToTensor())
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        mnist,
        batch_size=1,
        sampler=RepeatClassSampler(
            targets=mnist.targets,
            repeat_count=5,
            length=15,      # How many total to pick from your dataset
            shuffle=True))

for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
    # training loop
    print(f'Batch {idx+1} labels: {y.tolist()}')
```